# Mysql select a field conditionally

Tags: mysql

i've 10 databases and each one contains a users table with the following structure :
ID,Name,Email,Address

but for some reason the fields Email AND/OR Address are missing in some users table

I'm trying to merge all this data using this query (by changing only the DB name in the query) :

```
SELECT ID, CASE
         WHEN EXISTS(
            SELECT * FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'users' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'Email' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='DB1'
         )
           THEN  Email 
         ELSE ''
       END from `users`
, CASE
         WHEN EXISTS(
            SELECT * FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'users' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'Address' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='DB1'
         )
           THEN  Address 
         ELSE ''
       END from `users`
```

but for some tables i'm getting this error

> Unknown column 'Email' in 'field list'

OR

> Unknown column 'Address' in 'field list'

Any idea on how to solve this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Does the column Email and Address both exist in the users table?

Comment: for example in DB1 They both exists but in DB2 there's only Email and in DB3 there's only Address and in DB4 none of them